# write equation in latex with parenthesis horizontal

Tags: latex

How could I write the following equation including parenthesis and description for both terms in latex (predicted well, simple model) ,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `underbrace{}`:

`$ ... = ... \left\{\underbrace{|| \mathbf{Y} - ... ||^2}_{\text{using underbrace}} + ... \right\}$`

Note that the text is in math mode, so for the description you need to use `\text{}` to switch back to normal text.

Answer (score 1):

My sketch of the above equation:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\[
W^*=\min_W\Big\{%
\underbrace{\color{red}||Y-XW||^2}_{\color{red}\textrm{Predict well}}+%
\underbrace{\color{green!70!black}\lambda\,||W||^2_F}_{\color{green!70!black}\textrm{Simple model}}%
\Big\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of output]